# How can I extract multipart tar files from the command-line on macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, tar

I have multiple 2 GiB gzipped-tar files (`.tgz`) I downloaded from an online service with Safari. It's a Google Takeout of my entire photos library.

As each file downloaded, Safari automatically decompressed them so in the end I had 21 `tar` files in my Downloads folder.

How can I extract the contents of these multiple `tar` files?

Comment: You might want to try [The UnArchiver](https://macpaw.com/the-unarchiver) app from MacPaw. It is **free**, and works great. If you don't like the deep dive it takes sometimes to open multiple archives, this is the app for you. _Note: No financial or any other stake in MacPaw Way Ltd._ They just make excellent apps. Gemini 2 is also one of my favorites.

Comment: In the terminal, do `open *.tar`.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/terminal/apdc52250ee-4659-4751-9a3a-8b7988150530/mac

Comment: @lhf did you test that? I think you’ll find that doesn’t work

Comment: @Thinkr the guide only specifies extracting a single tar archive. This question is about extracting a multipart tar archive

Comment: @deed02392, it works fine for me. I tested it. How did it fail for you?

Comment: I can’t remember how exactly it didn’t work. You should add it as an answer if it’s definitely a solution.

Answer (score 4):

The `tar` command-line program on macOS only supports a single filename as an argument. However a valid workaround is to concatenate multi-part `tar` archives and pipe this to `tar`'s standard input. This can be achieved with the following example.

Given a directory of multiple `tar` files, the following command would extract their contents to the current directory, listing each file as it's extracted:

```
$ cat *.tar | tar --options read_concatenated_archives -xvf -
```

This assumes the files are named in the directory with the correct order for shell globbing.

Answer (score 0):

In the Terminal, do

```
cd ~/Downloads ; open *.tar
```

(as a side effect, it opens the Downloads folder in the Finder)

It also works for `*.tar.gz` and `*.tgz`.

Comment: This is a reasonable strategy, but it invokes LaunchServices to figure out the right binary to handle tar files, which is a lot of unnecessary overhead and more fragile than a direct command-line approach referring to the `tar` binary on `$PATH`. It also has the side-effect you mentioned of opening Finder (possibly because it uses Archive Utility to do the extraction).